# Align centered vertical and horizontally irregular thumbnails

Tags: css, html

Asking this question again because it was labeled as a duplicate (which it is NOT), and I feel like it just got buried.  Please read before you mark this as just another duplicate of another thread.

I'm trying to center align some irregular shaped thumbnails into a grid that breaks into columns as the browser window shrinks.  I'm really close with this code, however I need captions under each image.  I can't find an answer to this question.  I thought figcaption would work, but its getting aligned weirdly.  The max size a thumbnail could be is 200px^2.  All these thumbnails keep their proportions.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t19znqbe/)

```
//CSS
.centered {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;  /* for testing only */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    float:left;
}

//HTML
<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="" />
    <figcaption>This text isn't working properly</figcaption>
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x160" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x200" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to change in your html. You should take `image` and `figcaption` in `figure` tag.

```css
.centered {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;  /* for testing only */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    float:left;
}
figure{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
figure img{
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <figure>
     <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="" />
     <figcaption>This text isn't working properly</figcaption>     
    </figure>
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x160" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x200" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ooooh, figcaption makes more sense now.  I didn't know about the figure tag.  Just read up on it.  Makes total sense.  Thank you!